# background color in safari not working

Tags: safari, background-color

I am trying to get the background color to appear in safari and it is not working. it works in chrome and firefox but no luck in safari. serious answers only please. here is my code i have in css.

`main {`
`background-color: rgb(254, 236, 89, 0.85);`
`width: 960px;`
`padding-top: 130px;`
`padding-bottom: 87px;`
`}`

Comment: Please mark Andrew Maney's answer as the correct solution so that people can find it faster.

Answer (score 2):

In order to set an opacity on a background color you need to set the alpha of your color. So your color should be an `rgba` value, not `rgb`:

```
main { 
   background-color: rgba(254, 236, 89, 0.85); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
background-color: rgb(254, 236, 89, 0.85);
```

please try to use:

```
background-color: rgb(254, 236, 89);
opacity: 0.85;
```

so the complete solution will look like:

```
.main { background-color: rgb(254, 236, 89); opacity: 0.85; width: 960px; padding-top: 130px; padding-bottom: 87px; }
```

Hope this is the solution you were looking for.

Comment: Setting an opacity is not the same as setting the alpha channel on a background.

Comment: by doing that it changes the opacity of everything. instead i just did               background-color rgb(254, 236, 89) and background-color rgba(254, 236, 89, 0.85)        this seemed to solve across all platforms